# What is the "right" way to track a custom patch to a contributed module?

Tags: 6, version-control

I need to apply this patch to my site:
http://drupal.org/node/483176#comment-5939648

What is the "right" or "responsible" way to track this change? We use Git for version control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I keep all of those in the projects make file, which makes it easy to apply the patch again should the module be updated without it commited, and remove it when it's no longer necessary.

This answer makes the most sense in context of my [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26316/should-i-source-control-contribed-modules-in-my-project/26318#26318) to the question [Should I source control contribed modules in my project?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26316/should-i-source-control-contribed-modules-in-my-project/26318#26318).

Comment: Interesting, that makes a lot of sense. Reading... thanks!